# Undefined index in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

i'm getting the message "Undefined index: name..." in an sql insert query.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."')";
```

could someone tell me what is wrong?

ok, here is the (additional) code:

```
$name=(isset($_POST['name']));
$sql="INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."')";

<form action="index.php" method="post" id="enterForm">
<p>Enter username:</p>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input type="submit" name="enter" id="enter" value="OK" />
</form>
```

Comment: There's no `name` field in `$_POST` when this statement is called.

Comment: There is nothing in that $_POST,before the query use a if isset(...

Comment: can you show ur HTML code ??? ,, the error means that your form is not posting the the value name

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending field with `name` name so you can't get it from `$_POST`.

Also, never do something like that! You can't trust any user input. Filter it first or, better, use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if(isset($_POST['name']))
{
//Sanitize $_POST['name'] before directly inserting it to the table
$sql="INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."')";
}
else
{
echo "No data";
}
```

Comment: Probably sanitize it?